# How to apply SVM model to new data using libsvm in MATLAB?

Tags: classification, svm, matlab, supervised-learning, libsvm

Suppose that I have trained and tested an SVM classifier with the following code:

```
load('Model and Optimized SVM Parameters1.mat');
TrainData = double(model.Train(:,1:end-1));
TargetTrain = double(model.Train(:,end));
TestData = double(model.Test(:,1:end-1));
TargetTest = double(model.Test(:,end));
option = ['-h 0 -s 0 -t 2 -q -c ',num2str(20.6062),' -g ',num2str(0.2331)] ;
MODEL = svmtrain ( TargetTrain , TrainData , option ) ;
[OutputTest , ClassificationAccuracy , dec_values] = svmpredict ( TargetTest , TestData , MODEL ) ;
```

Now I have a dataset **X** as the same format as **TrainData** or **TestData** which has no label and I want to classify the entries of **X** with the classifier that is described in **MODEL**. Something like:

```
OutputLabel = svmpredict ( X, MODEL ) ;
```

but seems that `svmpredict` always takes the desired label as an argument ([here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b91082/SVM/README))
How should I use the classifier described in `MODEL` for classifying a dataset (for example an `Image`) while I have no label for the data?

Comment: `OutputLabel = svmpredict (zeros(size(X,1),1), X, MODEL ) ;`

Comment: I think the title is misleading, it should be something like "How to predict test data using libsvm in MATLAB when labels are not known"

Answer (score 2):

From the [libsvm readme](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b91082/SVM/README):

> If labels of test data are unknown, simply use any random values.

So just use a vector of ones or zeroes or whatever you are using for labels. You won't be able to trust the classification accuracy output but the predictions will be usable.